# Unable to load single folder on external HD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery

On my external (NTFS formatted) HD I have a single folder (containing thousands of files) that will not load. On Windows it says the drive is corrupted and cannot be read. All the other folders on the hard drive load fine. Using a tool called Diskdigger I verified that the files were still there. I suppose I could just recover all the files in that program, but ideally I'd like to keep the file structure that is in that folder. Is this possible? What might be wrong?

Comment: ntfs has a 4 billion file limit, so I guess you are not exceeding this. What is the size of your partition? and which OS version are you using?

Comment: 930 GB, have access to windows and OS X

Comment: ahota, first of all **make a copy of those files in a safe place** with DiskDigger, RecuperaBit (disclosure: I am the developer) or other good programs. Only **after that** try to `chkdsk` the drive.

Comment: @fixer1234 whoops... :D Sorry about that.